# Fetch a credit card number from the CardIO adding on the STPView (Stripe) - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, cardio

I have been implementing a credit card page developed by use of the `CardIO` and the `Stripe` in the `iOS7`.

CardIO: https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK

Stripe: https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios

Wondering how to add a credit card number taken from the `CardIO` onto the `STPView` (Stripe).

Simply explain What I want to do is exactly the same as the Payment cards page in the BIZZBY app.

BIZZBY: http://www.bizzby.com/

Anyone genius helps me out?

Thank you.

Comment: that would be a serious security leak in those frameworks, if could do it.

Comment: Is it? Do you recommend any payment library instead of these?

Comment: no payment library shares those details with a 3rd person, so you can use any of them, if you are happy with no access for those details.