# Can Card.io integrate with Stripe, or is it strictly pre-integrated with PayPal?

Tags: android, ios, stripe-payments, card.io

A similar question was posted previously (it never got an answer). That question was asked before Card.io decided to go open source.

[Fetch a credit card number from the CardIO adding on the STPView (Stripe) - iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25062783/fetch-a-credit-card-number-from-the-cardio-adding-on-the-stpview-stripe-ios)

Interested to know whether Card.io supports Stripe as a compatible gateway.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Dave from card.io here.

card.io simply provides a way for you to collect credit card information from your customer, with that information being returned directly to your app. What your app then does with that information is entirely up to you.

card.io runs entirely on the mobile device. No servers, PayPal or otherwise, are involved.

Comment: Hi Dave, you know I exactly the same question when I first was checking out card.io.  I think the default PayPal logo throws people off...

Answer (score 1):

I have specifically used Card.io in my app on the App Store (Search Impulse Car on the app store if you want proof) with Stripe and did not implement PayPal.  There is an PayPal image that comes default, but it's easily removed.